# Pandas dataframe + groupby = failed zooming for x-axis ticks

Tags: python, pandas, plot, zooming

I am trying to plot some `pandas` dataframe data but, when it is organised into daily/monthly/yearly sums using `groupby`, the resulting plot cannot be zoomed correctly.

The zoom does work however the x-axis tickmarks don't update correctly. I can't work out the solution to this.

Example code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arraya = np.random.rand(1,100)[0]
arrayb = np.random.rand(1,100)[0]
arrayc = np.random.rand(1,100)[0]
arrayd = np.random.rand(1,100)[0]

day_counts = {'A': arraya,
              'B': arrayb,
              'C': arrayc,
              'D': arrayd}

#prepare data
df_days = pd.DataFrame(day_counts, index=pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=100))
#df_use = df_days.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.day]).sum()
df_use = df_days.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month]).sum()

#prepare percentages
df_use_perc = df_use.divide(df_use.sum(axis=1), axis=0).multiply(100) #percentages

my_colors = list(['orange', 'blue', 'purple', 'red'])

#plot the main subfigure (relative event types)
ax = df_use_perc.plot(kind='area', stacked=True, color=my_colors)
```

It is this line that causes the failure:

```
df_use = df_days.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month]).sum()
```

I can plot it just using the dataframe `df_days`, without using the `groupby` function and it works okay but I need to be able to sum up the months etc.

Plot:
[image]

Plot after zooming in massively (the whole x-axis is probably only a few seconds wide):
[image]

Comment: The provided answer gives the good solution (using a datetime index instead of MultiIndex), but just to comment on the original issue in the question: pandas currently does not yet support zooming plots where the x axis is not numerical or datetime (so eg strings, multi-index). See https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/15912 and https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7612

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can do the following:

```
x = df_days.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('MS')).sum()
x.div(x.sum(1), 0).mul(100).plot(kind='area', stacked=True, color=my_colors)
```

[image]

after zooming:

[image]

Explanation:

```
In [35]: x
Out[35]:
                    A          B          C          D
2012-01-01  14.739981  18.306502  11.659834  13.990243
2012-02-01  13.180681  12.487874  15.367421  16.877128
2012-03-01  14.528299  16.936493  16.467844  16.668185
2012-04-01   4.190121   3.110165   5.165066   3.086899

In [36]: x.div(x.sum(1), 0).mul(100)
Out[36]:
                    A          B          C          D
2012-01-01  25.112171  31.188374  19.864594  23.834861
2012-02-01  22.759411  21.563123  26.535309  29.142158
2012-03-01  22.489341  26.217149  25.491695  25.801815
2012-04-01  26.942217  19.998167  33.211047  19.848569
```

Comment: thanks! changing from `groupby` to `pd.TimeGrouper` solved the problem. However I don't understand the explanation?  Simply changing the `groupby` to `TimeGrouper` fixed the problem, without changing how it calculates the percentages (the `df_use_perc` line of code) at all

Comment: @mjp, yes, using `TimeGrouper` generates an index of `datetime` dtype. I just didn't want to create additional variables.

Comment: ahh okay. I see now. The `groupby` method creates a date setup with `2012 1 A B C D`, while the TimeGrouper solution creates the dataframe with a date setup of `2012-01-01 A B C D` where it's marked by a datetime of the first day of the date period